# How can I access local files from a RESTFul web service

Tags: java, rest, glassfish-3

I try to access a local file from a RESTFul service.
Is there any way to get the real path of the running service ? (as we can do in a servlet)

Server : glassfish 3.0.1
IDE : Eclipse Helios

Thx

Comment: Well, it's Java, I don't know why you couldn't do this. Have you tried ? Can we see your code ?

Answer (score 6):

Which framework you are using for REST web service? 
You can get the real path in Jersey by following way:

```
@Context ServletContext context //you can specify in your method argument
String realPath = context.getRealPath("/");
```

Think will help you.

Comment: Thanks. That works just fine. I'm using Jersey but, for some reason, I didn't think I could inject the ServletContext (I was stuck with UriInfo, Request and HttpHeaders). I guess it was a stupid question...Not enough reading. Thanks again.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you. Can you please accept the answer. Will help other guys too in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
@Context ServletContext context;//you can specify this above method as annotation

String realPath = context.getRealPath("/");
```